# Matching number except 1 and 0

Tags: java, regex

How I can get all number except first 0 and 1, for example from 043241.124.22, I need to get 43241.24.22.
I have written code

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[2-9]");
String[] split = number.split("\\.")
String n = "";
Matcher m = p.matcher(split[0])
m.find();
n += split[0].substring(matchere.start()) + "."
....
```

but I think it can do by one or two line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `replaceAll()`, scanning for a `0` or `1` digit leading other digits, i.e.

- a `0` or `1` digit: `[01]`
- not preceded by a digit: `(?<=^|\D)` or `(?<!\d)`
- and followed by at least one digit: `(?=\d)`

Regex to find those is: `(?<=^|\D)[01](?=\d)`

Java code is:

```
String n = number.replaceAll("(?<=^|\\D)[01](?=\\d)", "");
```

See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/o4wRHV) for working code.

Comment: @JNat If you need to remove all leading `0` and `1` digits, add `+` after `[01]`. Don't know what rule you want for eliminating `-22`. Perhaps if you **learned regular expressions**, you could define the rule yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should use  loop. Hope this will help.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[2-9]");
String[] split = number.split("\\.");
String n = "";
for(int i=0;i<split.length;i++)
{
Matcher m = p.matcher(split[i]);
m.find();
n += split[i].substring(m.start())+".";

}
System.out.println(n);
```

Comment: can  I combine to pattern Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[2-9]"); and 
String[] split = number.split("\\.");